# Write a dictionary to csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have a dictionary and i want to write it into the csv file. I converted it into the list and tried to write into the csv file. I am getting the answer but not in the same format as i required.
This is my code

```
dic1 = {
    'Data': {
        'p_1': {
            'name': 'John', 
            'Interests': ['football', 'cricket']},
        'p_2': {
            'name': 'Smith', 
            'Interests': ['baseball', 'cricket']
                    }}}
import csv
import pandas
for k,v in dic1.items():
    val_list = []
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        key = list(v1.keys())
        val = list(v1.values())
        val_list.append(val)

# wite the data into the csv file
with open('names.csv', 'w') as f:
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(key)
    write.writerows(val_list)
    print('The file has been written')

# read the csv file with pandas
res = pandas.read_csv('names.csv')
print(res)
```

I got the output in this way:

```
    name                Interests
0   John  ['football', 'cricket']
1  Smith  ['baseball', 'cricket']
```

But required format is:

```
    name                Interests
0   John        football, cricket
1  Smith        baseball, cricket
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame({y:z for k,v in dic1.items() for y,z in v.items()}.values())
#The above code doing the same thing via dict comprehension,here dic1 is your dictionary
df['Interests']=df['Interests'].str.join(',')
df.to_csv('names.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the line:

```py
    write.writerows(val_list)
```

into:

```py
    write.writerows(' '.join(map(str, val_list))
```

Remember, doing so will not make the life of:

```py
res = pandas.read_csv('names.csv')
```

any easier. it might not read the things as it used to be.